# Smooth scroll script and slider not working together

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, slider, smooth-scrolling

I have a website with a slider and a smooth scroll script. The problem is, I can't get them to work at the same time.

This is the url:
http://kop.hosts.ma-cloud.nl/template/

can somebody please tell me what i'm doing wrong? I am already using var jq = $.noConflict();

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Inspect your code, you have 2 errors

Comment: Thanks a lot, kind of a noob I'm afraid...Can you give me a hint?

Comment: I just realized what you meant (inspect element in chrome), and ik think i fixed one error. Not sure how to fix the second one..

Comment: I created a jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/zlen/8n9b8w8g/ - Please take the habit to use this kind of tools to explain your problem

Comment: Thanks! I can see why that's helpfull.

Comment: Your code is strange. I don't understand everything, you should rework that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have a everything working. Please add following corrections to make it full functional.

**Step 1** 
Load jQuery library (jquery.min.js) before jQuery-ui library like below:

```
<!--Script voor smooth scroll-->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Script voor de slider-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

**Step 2** 
Remove this line.

```
// var jq = $.noConflict();
```

**Step 3** 
Remove all instances of *jq* with *$* in the following section like my version:

```
$('.rightarrow, .leftarrow').hide();

$('#scrolldiv_container').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.rightarrow, .leftarrow').show();
    clearInterval(siId);
})
$('#scrolldiv_container').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.rightarrow, .leftarrow').hide();
        si();
});

$('.rightarrow').click(function () {
    var leftPos = $('#browser').scrollLeft();
    <!--1000 * 6 (aantal slides - 1)-->
    if (leftPos == 6000) {
        $('#browser').animate({
            scrollLeft: 0
        }, 400);
    } else {
        $('#browser').animate({
            scrollLeft: leftPos + 1000
        }, 150);
    }
});

$('.leftarrow').click(function () {
    var leftPos = $('#browser').scrollLeft();
    if (leftPos == 0) {
        $('#browser').animate({
            <!--1000 * 6 (aantal slides - 1)-->
            scrollLeft: 6000
        }, 400);
    } else {
        $('#browser').animate({
            scrollLeft: leftPos - 1000
        }, 150);
    }
});
```

**Step 4** 
Now reload the page and you will see both the slider and smooth scrolling are working.

Comment: That's super helpfull, thanks a lot! Question, how can you paste code so easily? I tried when I was writing my original question, but all i could find was 4 spaces in front of the code, and that made kind of a mess. Thanks again!